# Using a for-loop to create new boxes and then to create an href

Tags: javascript, href

```
var parent = document.getElementById('images-digtal'),
    imagePath = '_digital.jpg',
    img;

for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) { 
    img = new Image();
    img.src = [i]+ imagePath;
     parent.appendChild(img);
}
```

Within this for-loop, I have it so that the loop is creating a new image every single time it loops.

How do I add a different `href` every single time it loops?
For example:

1. Box `www.google1.com`
2. Box `www.google2.com`
3. Box `www.google3.com`

Comment: images don't have hrefs

Comment: `[i]` makes no sense. You are making an array and it calls toString() which returns the string. Just do `i + imagePath;`

Comment: If you want an anchor wrapped around it than it is two elements needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an anchor wrapped around the image, than you create an anchor, create the image, and append the image to the anchor, and than the anchor to the document

```
var parent = document.getElementById('images-digtal'),
    imagePath = '_digital.jpg';

for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
  // create anchor
  var anchor = document.createElement("a");
  anchor.href = "http://ww.example.com/" + i;
  // create image
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = i + imagePath;
  // add image to anchor
  anchor.appendChild(img)
  // add anchor to document
  parent.appendChild(anchor);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!